# Как сделать чтобы бот писал участников голосвого канала? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

вот например пользователь пишут определенную команду и в это время он находится в голосовом канале с несколькими другими участниками и бот будет писать ники всех участников голосового канала в котором сидит  автор команды

Comment: При вызове команды нужно получить голосовой канал автора команды, а затем из объекта канала получить всех остальных пользователей. Из объектов пользователей можно получить ники и вывести их в сообщение

Comment: можно код? я просто не знаю как из обьекта вывести пользователей и вывести их ники

Comment: К сожалению, на StackOverflow не принято просить готовый код. Попробуйте сделать самостоятельно и если что-то не получится - спросите, приложив код, который не работает. Хотя вам уже дали хороший ответ

Comment: ```emb.add_field(name = "участники", value = ctx.author.voice.channel.members)``` Это строчка кода по которой бот получает список участников войс канала, но когда я вывожу его вот такая ошибка - imgur.com/a/VQF7utv

Comment: В чем ошибка? Вы вывели в embed строковое представление списка участников - сообщение отправилось. Все правильно. Я уже писал выше, что вам нужно вывести не сам список участников, а только ники каждого отдельного элемента этого списка. Ник можно получить по свойству `name`, применив его к отдельному участнику.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.command()
async def members_voice(ctx):
    await ctx.send(', '.join([member.mention for member in ctx.author.voice.channel.members]))
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/VQF7utv

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: А что не так? Бот отправляет объекты всех пользователей на голосовом канале

Answer (score 0):

```py
@bot.command(aliases=["MIV"])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)  # если хотите, чтобы команда была доступна только админам
async def members_in_voice(ctx):
    c = 1
    for member in ctx.author.voice.channel:
        await ctx.author.create_dm()
        await ctx.author.dm_channel.send(
            f'{c}) {member.name}'
        )
        c += 1
```